# How to save last place of point in a buffer?

Tags: buffers, point

I would like to save the last position of point in the buffer I am visiting, so to have point still there when I go back to that file.

I understand I can use `saveplace` for this, so I added this snippet in my configuration:

```el
(use-package saveplace ; Save point position in files
  :init (progn
          (setq-default save-place t)
          (toggle-save-place-globally)))
```

Yet I am not getting the desired behavior: point is still place at the beginning of the buffer.

I am using Emacs 25.0.50.1 (`45c92dd`), but the same thing is happening with `emacs -Q`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I am using Emacs 25.0.50.8 and I noticed the behavior of the `save-place` variable has been changed:

> This variable is obsolete since 25.1; use `save-place-mode' instead.

You can type `C-h v save-place` to read its full documentation.

Below is my config:

```
(use-package saveplace
  :init (save-place-mode))
```

Comment: There's not much use in `:defer t`, since calling `save-place-mode` in `:init` will trigger loading immediately anyway.

Comment: @npostavs You are right. I forgot that requiring already loaded feature has no effect. I'll update my answer. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Is there a list somewhere of things I need to update after upgrading to Emacs 25 so that other things like this don't break?

Comment: @incandescentman Yes, just read the Emacs NEWS via `C-h n` (`view-emacs-news`), you can also pass a prefix argument to limit it to one specific version such as 25.1.

Comment: When I added this config to my init.el I got an error: `Symbol's function definition is void: use-package`

Comment: @GrantBowman Looks like you don't use `use-package`, thus all you need is `(save-place-mode)`.